# Fade-in images when scrolling down a page

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, scroll, fadein

I'm looking for code or a wordpress plug-in to do a simple fade-in of images when scrolling down a page. View example here: http://www.wielaretsarchitects.com/en/projects/avb_tower/

I'm using a wordpress theme and modifying a lot of things; I need subtle effects for a PROJECTS page, when scrolling through a vertical column of images.

Thanks a ton for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

So what you want is referred to as "lazy-loading". I quickly found this [WP plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/lazy-load/), so you can try it, but there are some really simple solutions to the problem you could do on your own, like this one from [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/lazy-loading-images/) or even one I wrote up on [my blog](http://trentwillis.net/blog/images-loading-slow-get-lazy/).

Comment: Danke! Exactly what I need.